# NoReverseMatch at /shop/ django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have an error on my site (http://datat.ru/shop/)

> Reverse for 'shop_detail' not found. 'shop_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**How can I solve it?**

This is my code. I checked `<h1><a href="{% url 'shop_detail' pk=shop.pk %}">{{shop.title}}</h1>` it seems ok.
I think that problem deals with urls.py, but didn't find it(

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('shop/', views.shop_list, name='shop'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('shop/<int:pk>/', views.shop_detail, name='shop_detail'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post, Company
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
def shop_list(request):
    shops = Company.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/shop_list.html', {'shops': shops})
def shop_detail(request, pk):
    shop = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/shop_detail.html', {'shop': shop})
```

**html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin:40px;">
  <div class="row">
    <!--<div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-5">-->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h6 class="text-muted">List Group with Cards</h6>
      <ul class="list-group">
        {% for shop in shops %}
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <!-- Vacancy start -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                     <h1><a href="{% url 'shop_detail' pk=shop.pk %}">{{shop.title}}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                        <p> 40000
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="white-space:normal">
                  <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                    <p> Описание вакансии: Компания Sixhands, занимающаяся разработкой мобильных приложений и веб-порталов в Санкт-Петербурге, ищет Backend-разработчика для создания серверной части мобильных приложений.
                    <footer class="blockquote-footer"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p> CompanyName {{shop.title}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                <p> PublishDate
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </footer>
                  </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Vacancy end -->
        </li>
       {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hit a random 404 page and found that you don't have a url named in `shop_detail` in server. This is what the error says:

[image]

So you need to update your code in the server(specifically the urls) and probably restart your server as well(as I don't know you have configured django or how you have configured NGINX).